# How to edit instance variable from inside a method? non-static variable sum cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, object, methods, static, instance

```
public class Sum{

    int sum = 0;

    public static void sum_do(String array[]){
        int tmpi = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; ++i){
            tmpi = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
            sum += tmpi;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to modify sum variable, but I am unable to do that.

```
./Sum.java:9: error: non-static variable sum cannot be referenced from a static context
                        sum += tmpi;
                        ^
1 error
```

I'm really new to Java, so this is probably some very easy stuff

Comment: You cannot refer to an instance variable directly unless it's static. You can either declare the instance variable ,`sum` as static to access it inside the method. 
Example: `static int sum = 0;` 
OR 
You need to create an object of your class to access this instance variable like,
`Sum mySum = new Sum();`
`mySum.sum += tmpi;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you try to reach a non-static var in a static context, try:

```
static int sum = 0;
```